# node webkit - gclient sync on Windows 7 missing base_window.h

Tags: python, windows, chromium, node-webkit

So I've been trying to compile Node Webkit on Windows for a while now and I've gotten stuck on this error that no amount of Googling can help me resolve.

I run `gclient sync` on my windows `cmd` and it always errors with

`________ running 'C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe src/build/
gyp_chromium' in 'C:\www\node-webkit'
Updating projects from gyp files...
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\www\node-webkit\src\content\..\chrome\browser\ui\base_window.h
C:\www\node-webkit\src\content\nw\src\breakpad_linux_impl.h
Hook ''C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe' src/build/gyp_chromi
um' took 69.74 secs`

I've checked permissions of the files as well and given my user all rights to all the files and I've tried running `cmd` as an administrator, it makes no difference.

I can't work it out at all and I can't find anything on Google. Here is the full output from `gclient sync` for brevity, can anyone assist in why it worked fine on OSx and I can't get any success from Winblows?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\www\node-webkit>gclient sync
Syncing projects:   3% ( 3/88) src/chrome/tools/test/reference_build/chrome_linu
Syncing projects:   4% ( 4/88) src/chrome/tools/test/reference_build/chrome_mac
Syncing projects:   6% ( 6/88) src/chrome_frame/tools/test/reference_build/chrom
Syncing projects:   7% ( 7/88) src/chrome_frame/tools/test/reference_build/chrom
Syncing projects:   9% ( 8/88) src/chrome/test/data/perf/third_party/octane
Syncing projects:  10% ( 9/88) src/chrome/test/data/extensions/api_test/permissi
Syncing projects:  11% (10/88) src/chrome/test/data/perf/canvas_bench
Syncing projects:  98% (87/88), done.

________ running 'C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe src/build/
download_nacl_toolchains.py --no-arm-trusted --keep' in 'C:\www\node-webkit'

________ running 'C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe src/build/
linux/install-arm-sysroot.py --linux-only' in 'C:\www\node-webkit'

________ running 'C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe src/chrome
/installer/linux/sysroot_scripts/install-debian.wheezy.sysroot.py --linux-only -
-arch=amd64' in 'C:\www\node-webkit'

________ running 'C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe src/chrome
/installer/linux/sysroot_scripts/install-debian.wheezy.sysroot.py --linux-only -
-arch=i386' in 'C:\www\node-webkit'

________ running 'C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe src/tools/
clang/scripts/update.py --mac-only' in 'C:\www\node-webkit'

________ running 'C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe src/build/
win/setup_cygwin_mount.py --win-only' in 'C:\www\node-webkit'

________ running 'C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe src/build/
util/lastchange.py -o src/build/util/LASTCHANGE' in 'C:\www\node-webkit'

________ running 'C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe src/build/
util/lastchange.py -s src/third_party/WebKit -o src/build/util/LASTCHANGE.blink'
 in 'C:\www\node-webkit'

________ running 'download_from_google_storage --platform=win32 --directory --bu
cket chromium-gn src/tools/gn/bin/win' in 'C:\www\node-webkit'

________ running 'download_from_google_storage --platform="linux*" --directory -
-bucket chromium-gn src/tools/gn/bin/linux' in 'C:\www\node-webkit'

________ running 'C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe src/build/
gyp_chromium' in 'C:\www\node-webkit'
Updating projects from gyp files...
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\www\node-webkit\src\content\..\chrome\browser\ui\base_window.h
C:\www\node-webkit\src\content\nw\src\breakpad_linux_impl.h
Hook ''C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe' src/build/gyp_chromi
um' took 69.74 secs

________ running 'C:\depot_tools\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe src/build/
landmines.py' in 'C:\www\node-webkit'

C:\www\node-webkit>
```

Comment: have you tried building it with the ninja command ?